# jQuery Mobile Slideup and slide down popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile in my application. I am creating a Popup using the following code:

```
$(element).click(function () {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlay").popup({
        transition: "slideup",
        shadow: false,
        corners: false,
        positionTo: "window"
    }).popup("open");
});
```

And then when the user clicks the close button I have the following code for the slide down:

```
$("#close").click(function () {
    $("#overlay").popup({ transition: "slidedown" });
})
```

The slide up works as expected but slide down does not even respond. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've commented before on your previous duplicate question. The transition will be reversed, you don't have to do anything, JQM will do it for you. Slideup -> close popup -> slidedown.

Comment: If I simply do a .popup("close") I do not see the "sidedown" transition happening! Can I make the speed slow so I can actually see the slide down transition.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/7ebnvacj/1/

Comment: Thanks Robert! Weird that it does not work for me.

Comment: @RobertRozas you dont event need the close button, clicking the popup's overlay will close it automatically since its a _dismissible popup_.

Comment: Hi Omar! For some reason it is not closing and even if it close it does not perform a transition = slide down.

Comment: @Omar , i was just following the OP code sample...

Comment: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6be4839f/ @RobertRozas It was just a side note :)

Comment: You call open first and I call popup first. Anyways, for some reason the slide down is not working. Thanks for yr help!

Comment: it doesn't matter when you call `open`, it will work either way. `$("#overlay").show()` isn't needed here anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jzt70h0q/

Comment: If you call "open" first then the other options like shadow and corners do not take effect. So, calling open last ensures that the options will take effect.